# Automatic exchange of synonyms for SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords

If I have a website that targets a certain audience, but the keywords that are being searched for have a lot of synonyms that are being used equally often, would it make sense to exchange these words on my page on every user visit?

For example, I want to optimize for the keywords "seminar", "training", "workshop" (and maybe some more). Using all of the keywords on the same page without enumerating them is difficult, especially if there is not a lot of text on the page.

- Would it be a good idea to swap these words for SEO everytime the page is called?
- Is that somehow frowned upon and penalized by search engines?
- Would that actually do any good, or would it just lower my ranking for each of these keywords because each of them is shown less often?

Comment: Is it possible to move it or do I have to reopen there?

Comment: we can. just flag it for a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you remove one word and swap it out for another then you'll stop ranking better for the original word and start ranking better for the swapped out word. That is counter-productive. Just pick the word that is most appropriate and go with that. If all of the words are appropriate (really one should fit better then the rest) then choose the one that gets the most searches (the [Google Adwords tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none) can help you figure that out).